# Getting addresses or LatLng within a radius of current location

Tags: android, google-maps, parsing

I am developing an app where it would show "events" that is within a 50 meter radius of the current location of the user. I would get these events from an online database. These events contain a LatLng and an address from the DB.

I already implemented location updates.

My question is that what approach would be better?

One approach:

I draw circle on the current location using `addCircle`. Then remove and redraw these circles when the current location changes.

The hard part about this is how would I get the locations or lat/lang within 50 meters.

I would then query my DB and return my events.

Another approach I've considered is Geofences. I am still studying it right now.
Maybe I would draw a geofence around my current location and update it as needed.

Comment: i recommend you using circles,calculate the distance of all latlongs with the circle latlong and check for the condition which all latlongs are inside the radius.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a function called

```
InRadius(centerX, centerY, radius, x, y) 
{
Return (radius * 111000f) >= sqrt((x-centerX )^2 +(y-centerY) ^2) 
}
```

Center is user location. But you must call on every record in event table, feeding the lat into y and the long into x

Comment: That's correct. X is long, y is lat, but you can rename those parameters if that helps. I edited my answer. And I fixed a bug.

Comment: hmm these will work too. Since `LatLng` format is in decimal, I'm also trying another approach because I saw a helper method in the DB API which you can do a query of less than/greater than, how would you get the upper/lower bound x and y (4 values) within a given center and a radius.

Comment: Well, in sql it would be similar. `Select * from event where (radius * 111000.0) >= sqrt((x-centerX )^2 +(y-centerY) ^2)`

Comment: Ah Im using Parse SDK but nonetheless i will try something similar to sql

Comment: @Smaran, yes it's in meters

Comment: @toddmo..
Here is the code i am trying

'(radius * 111000f) >= Math.sqrt((13.0394485-centerX )*(13.0394485-centerX ) +(77.5691246-centerY) *(77.5691246-centerY));'

so i want the radius to be inside 500 m 
I had passed the value of radius as 500, so when i was outside the radius of 500 it still gave me stating i am inside radius

Answer (score 4):

```
public static LatLng getLocation(double lon, double lat, int radius) 
{
    Random random = new Random();

    // Convert radius from meters to degrees
    double radiusInDegrees = radius / 111000f;

    double u = random.nextDouble();
    double v = random.nextDouble();
    double w = radiusInDegrees * Math.sqrt(u);
    double t = 2 * Math.PI * v;
    double x = w * Math.cos(t);
    double y = w * Math.sin(t);

    // Adjust the x-coordinate for the shrinking of the east-west distances
    double new_x = x / Math.cos(lat);

    double foundLongitude = new_x + lon;
    double foundLatitude = y + lat;
    System.out.println("Longitude: " + foundLongitude + "  Latitude: "
            + foundLatitude);

    return new LatLng(foundLatitude, foundLongitude);

}
```

Then call function where you want. :)

```
private LatLng latlon1;

    latlon1 = getLocation(location.getLongitude(),location.getLatitude(),50);
```

->location = your current location
->50 = radius what ever you want to give

hope you get your answer :)

Comment: I am not following the use of random in your function. Can you explain that? Your final function output indirectly depends on these random numbers. Maybe that was testing code you forgot to take back out?

Comment: Random function will give me 1 random LatLng near my location.its not depended on

Comment: Yes it does depend. foundLongitude <= new_x <= x <= t <= v <= Random. Using the function as you instruct will not have the desired result. These need to be parameters, and if you want to call it for example with random address, that is fine. Can you see why you don't mix test code with the logic in your function OP is supposed to call? If someone just copies your function, they will get wrong results. Thanks.

Comment: Thank You.. great answer